# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'in/home/vhosts/www.********.com/process-form.php on line 18

Tags: php, sql

I very new with database and just trying to follow a Youtube video and even used their code but get this error.I'm not sure if I have the host, dbname, username, or password mixed up.

```
DataBase name: 1152931`your text`
DataBase username: 1152931
DataBase password: equal with account password
DataBase host: localhost
```

```
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbname = "1152931";
    $username = "1152931";
    $password = "********";

    $conn = mysqli_connect(hostname: $localhost,
                           username: $username,
                           password: $password,
                           database: $dbname);

     if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
         die("Connection error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
     }           
 
     $sql = "INSERT INTO message (name, body, priority, type)
             VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
 
     $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
```

Comment: Inside your `mysqli_connect` function, remove `hostname:`, `username:`, etc. Those are called parameter hints which is a feature of IDEs.

Comment: You should have php 8 for this to wok.